# How set conditions in column

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I try to set brackets {} after the arrow function, but the result is ever null

```
return Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText);
```

I want to set something like this:

```
return Array.from(rows, row => {
            const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
            return Array.from(columns, column => {
                if(column.href.includes('new-york-time')){
                    console.log('well link')
                }
                column.innerText;
                });
```

Comment: Nick is correct that you need to return something from the map's callback, but it's a good idea to explain what you're actually trying to achieve here. If you have a mapping function with an `if` inside the callback, you might be looking for a filtering function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) expects returned values in the callback function, but you haven't returned anything from it

You can check these examples

No brackets - Returning `column.innerText` directly

```
return Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText); //correct
```

Brackets and no return (incorrect)

```
return Array.from(columns, column => {
  column.innerText //incorrect
});
```

Brackets and a return (correct)

```
return Array.from(columns, column => {
  return column.innerText //correct
});
```

For your case, you can modify it like this

```
return Array.from(rows, row => {
            const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
            return Array.from(columns, column => {
                if(column.href.includes('new-york-time')){
                    //TODO: Do something with your condition
                    console.log('well link')
                }
                return column.innerText; //return here
            });
```